# Fastest locking strategy (isolation level) for single user batch job

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, locking, isolation-level

We have a SQL Server 2005 database that contains preprocessed data for reports.

All data is deleted and rebuild from scratch every night, based on data from the production database.

During the night the job is the only thing running on that server, so I have no simultaneous access to my data.

We are currently using the default `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level.

I understand that SQL Server will put locks on tables, for reading and writing. Since no one else is touching my tables (both the tables I read and those I write) while my job is running, would it be faster to specify `WITH (NOLOCK)`, or using exclusive table locks `(TABLOCKX)` ?

Thanks for any hints,

Yves

Comment: SQL Server will put locks on **rows** - not tables - by default. Only if a transaction exceeds 5000 concurrent locks, SQL Server will do a **lock escalation** and lock the table (instead of 5000+ individual rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably won't notice any difference from a CPU-usage standpoint. `READ COMMITTED` does not even take S-locks on rows that sit on pages that do not have uncommitted rows on them. This is a little known optimization in SQL Server for the very common `READ COMMITTED` isolation level.

I recommend that you consider `READ UNCOMMITTED` (which is exactly equivalent to `NOLOCK`) or `TABLOCK` because it allows SQL Server to scan tables in allocation order (an IAM scan) as opposed to logical index order. This is good for IO patterns and depending on the degree fragmentation can make a significant impact (or none at all).

For bulk writes look into the relevant guides put out by Microsoft. Make sure you take advantage of minimally-logged writes. `TABLOCKX` can come into play here.